# plotting a vbar_stack using a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I'm struggling to get a stacked vbar working.

With python/pandas and bokeh I want to plot several statistics about the players of a football team. The dataframe is nicely filled, the values are a string where they should be an `int` where it should be a numeric value.

I used the sample of bokeh to try and adjust it for my purpose, but I'm stuck on

```
'ValueError: Keyword argument sequences for broadcasting must be the same length as stackers' this error.
```

My code (without imports and scraping pieces) is:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=statsdfsource[['goals','assists','naam']])

p = figure(plot_height=250, title="Fruit Counts by Year",
       toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar_stack(['goals','assists'], x='naam', width=0.9, color=colors, 
source=source)

p.y_range.start = 0
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.axis.minor_tick_line_color = None
p.outline_line_color = None
p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"

show(p)
```

The dataframe I fill the `columndatasource` with is

```
    goals   assists naam
0   NaN NaN Miguel Santos
1   NaN NaN Aykut Özer
2   NaN NaN Job van de Walle
3   NaN NaN Rowen Koot
4   8.0 6.0 Perr Schuurs
5   4.0 2.0 Wessel Dammers
6   12.0    2.0 Stefan Askovski
7   1.0 NaN Mica Pinto
8   NaN NaN Christopher Braun
9   1.0 4.0 Marco Ospitalieri
10  NaN 1.0 Clint Esser
```

The result I want to reach is a stacked columnframe, where on the x-axis is the name of the player, with 2 columns above it, one with the goals the player made and one with the assists.

I think I'm messing up somewhere with how my dataframe is built, but I'm a bit floating how it should be formed (can't really imagine on the other hand that the dataframe doesn't fit the purpose).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using categorical ranges, you have to tell `figure` what the categories for the axis are and what order you want them to show up, e.g. provide `x_range` something like:

```
# specify all the factors for the x-axis by passing x_range
p = figure(..., x_range=sorted(df.naam.unique()))
```

It's also possible the `NaN` values are a problem, since they are "contagious". I'd recommend changing them to zeros instead in any case.

Finally the error message probably indicates that your `colors` list is the wrong length. You are stacking two bars in each column, so the list of colors needs to also be two (one color for each "row" in the stack).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i've adjusted the x_range and replaced the NaN with 0: but the script still quits with 'Keyword argument sequences for broadcasting must be the same length as stackers'.

Comment: Oh I missed that, is `colors` a list of length two? It has to be, you are stacking two things in each column.

Comment: ah man, you weren't the only one who missed the colors. I was looking over the obvious thing: colors wasn't declared with anything, now works like a charm, along with your suggestiong in the answer. Can you kick the colors answer in, so i can credit your answer? :)